# Can't navigate between screen on react-navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm developping react-navigation from different ways.
The trouble is on the last i have tried.

I am trying to navigate From HomeScreen to DetailScreen with a custom component (kind of button deported).
The trouble is : "TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.prop.navigation.navigate')

Does someone could help me to understand the problem ?
(N.B : I'm using react-navigation 5)

I give you the diffents files :

```
//fichier app.js

import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React from 'react';

import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen'
import DetailScreen from './src/detailscreen'

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

file HomeScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import ButtonNav from './Button';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    console.log('Home' + this.props)
    return (
      <View 
        style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

        <View 
          style={{height: 120, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>Zone 1</Text>
        </View>

        <ButtonNav/>

      </View>
    )
  }
}


export default HomeScreen;
```

Button

```
//Button

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class ButtonNav extends React.Component {

    render() {
      console.log(this.props.navigation)
      return (
        <View 
          style={{height: 120, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')}>
            <Text>Button</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  export default ButtonNav;
```

DetailScreen

```
//detail

import React  from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class Detail extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <View 
      style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Detail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the navigation property inside the Button class, you can pass it in that way:

```
<ButtonNav
  navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Or you can pass the event `onPress` by props:

```
<ButtonNav
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')} />

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={this.props.onPress}>
  <Text>Button</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Help me with this issue if you can? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606346/react-navigation-v5-pass-function-as-parameter-to-be-used-in-headerright-butto

Answer (score 0):

So in ButtonNav class, there are no props for this class.

include the piece of code in your class.

> ```
> constructor(props){
> super(props);
> }
> ```

Comment: if you only passing the props u don't need a constructor